# How to fetch data from collections when the route/template consist on more than collection?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Example:

**routes.js:**

```
this.route("chapterPage", {
  path: "/books/:bookId/chapters/:_id",
  data: function() {
    var chapter = Chapters.findOne(this.params._id);
    var book = Books.findOne(this.params.bookId);
    var chapters = Chapters.find({
      bookId: this.params.bookId
    }, {
      sort: {
        position: 1
      }
    });
    return {
      chapter: chapter,
      book: book,
      chapters: chapters
    };
  }
});
```

As you can see this template/route has two collections `Book` and `Chapter`. Previously, I used to call the collections individually like this:

**chapter_form.js:**

```
Template.chapterForm.events({
  "input #input-content": function() {
    var currentChapter = Session.get("currentChapter");
    Chapters.update(currentChapter, {
      $set: {
        content: $("#input-content").html();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

But now in my new route/template I can't do that since it isn't based on any collection:

**chapter_page.js:**

```
Template.chapterPage.events({
  "input #input-content": function() {
    console.log(chapter._id); // this returns is not defined 
    console.log(this._id); // this one too
  }
});
```

How to get around this?

**EDIT:**

I also tried calling the `chapter_form.html` template:

```
<template name="chapterPage">
  {{> chapterForm}}
</template>
```

But it doesn't display and shows stuff like: `Cannot read property 'content' of undefined` so it isn't recognizing the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

First in the `data` function of the `chapterPage` route, you do not `return` the object containing your data.

```
// no return here in your question, need to do :
return {
  chapter: chapter,
  book: book,
  chapters: chapters
};
```

Then in your event handler, you can access the data context using `this`, so the correct syntax to access the chapter or book id is `this.chapter._id` or `this.book._id`.

EDIT :

Inside templates route helpers and event handlers, `this` refers to the current data context assigned to the template.

There are several ways to assign a data context to a template.

You can use `attribute="value"` syntax along with template inclusion syntax.

```
{{> myTemplate param1="value1" param2="value2"}}

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  paramsJoined:function(){
    return [this.param1,this.param2].join(",");
  }
});
```

You may also use a helper value coming from the parent template data context :

```
<template name="parent">
  {{> myTemplate someHelper}}
</template>

Template.parent.helpers({
  someHelper:function(){
    return {
      param1:"value1",
      param2:"value2"
    };
  }
});
```

If you don't specify a data context when using the template inclusion syntax, it is assumed to be inherited from the parent data context.

You can also use `{{UI.dynamic}}` (http://docs.meteor.com/#ui_dynamic) to specify a dynamic template name along with a dynamic data context.

```
{{> UI.dynamic template=Router.template data=Router.data}}
```

This is this kind of approach that `iron:router` is using to set dynamically the route data context of the route template (implementation is slightly more complex though).

Meteor provides utilities to access current data contexts as well as parent data contexts, which can be useful :

http://docs.meteor.com/#template_currentdata

http://docs.meteor.com/#template_parentdata

Comment: Oh, sorry the `return` is in the actual code. I removed it accidentally.

Comment: This was confusing because I wondered how your template could display anything of interest without it !

Comment: Oh, thanks it worked. I've been puzzling about this for weeks. So `this` will always refer to the current `route` data?